# TFS REST API : to change build result from partially partiallySucceeded to succeeded

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops-rest-api

I Have a few build result set to `partiallySucceeded`. I want to set them as `Succeeded` using REST API.

I was looking into this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/update%20build?view=vsts-rest-4.1#buildstatus). Even though the API says that we can set, it's actually not changing the result.

The below is the REST call I am using:

```
Patch https://tfs/tfs/MyCollection/myProject/_apis/build/builds/31?api-version=4.0

Body: {
    "result": "succeeded"
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and can reproduce this issue, we can change any other values except the "`result`" value with the REST API.

For now as a workaround you can update `[Build].[tbl_Build]` table directly to change the "result" value. (**Please backup the DB first** before runing the update command):

```
update [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[Build].[tbl_Build] set [Result] = '2' where [BuildId]=157
```

Comment: thanks for trying and letting me know. The database query is not going to help me due to policy in my org. Is a bug filed for this to MS.

Comment: @Angshuman It's an expected result. The build result cannot be changed as soon as the build is finished.